# What are the advantages of using Prolog over other languages?

Tags: prolog

Every language that is being used is being used for its advantages, generally.

What are the advantages of [**Prolog**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog)?

What are the general situations/ category of problems where one can use Prolog more efficiently than any other language?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compared to what exactly? Prolog is really just the pre-eminent implementation of logic programming so if your question is really about a comparison of programming paradigms well that's really very broad indeed and you should look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_paradigm).

If your question is more specifically about prolog vs the more commonly seen OO languages I would argue that you're really comparing apples to oranges - the "advantage" (such as it is) is just a different way of thinking about the world, and sometimes changing the way you ask a question provides a better tool for solving a problem.

Comment: compared to C/C++ in particular... solving a 8 queens problem is for example, so easier in Prolog (which I just found out). Why is C vs Prolog like apples and oranges? Can't every C program be converted to Prolog and vice versa??

Comment: It can (in theory - i.e. I can't think of a counter-example offhand) but just because you can doesn't mean you should. Look at it this way: if it *was* the right choice most of the time then there'd be a lot more prolog programmers than there are.

Comment: @annakata yes, I agree. but I don't know why (there are less Prolog programmers)

Answer (score 5):

Basically, if your program can be stated easily as declaritive formal logic statements, Prolog (or another language in that family) will give the fastest development time. If you use a good Prolog compiler, it will also give the best performance and reliability, because the engine will have had a lot of design and development effort.

Trying to implement this kind of thing in another language tends to be a mess. The cleanest and most general solution probably involves implementing your own unification engine. Even naive implementations aren't exactly trivial, the Warren Abstract Machine has a book or two written about it, and doing better will at the very least involve a fair bit of research, reading some headache-inducing papers.

Of course in the real world, key parts of your program may benefit from Prolog, but a lot of other stuff is better handled using another language. That's why a lot of Prolog compilers can interface with, e.g., C.

Answer (score 3):

One of the best times to use Prolog is when you have a problem suited to solving with [backtracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking). And that is when you have lots of possible solutions to a problem, and perhaps you want to order them to include/exclude depending on some context. This suggests a lot of ambiguity... as in natural language processing.

It sure would be a lot tidier to write all the potential answers as Prolog clauses. With a imperative language all I think you can really do is write a giant (really giant) CASE statement, which is not too fun.

Answer (score 3):

The stuff that are inherent in Prolog:

- pattern matching!
- anything that involves a depth first search. ( in Java if you want to do a DFS, you may want to implement it by a visitor pattern or do a (really giant) CASE
- unification
- ??

Paul Graham, is a Lisp person nonetheless he argues that Prolog is really good for 2% of the problems, I am myself like to break this 2% down and figure how he'd come up with such number.

His argument for "better" languages is "less code, more power". Prolog is definitely "less code" and if you go for latter flavours of it (typed ones), you get more power too. The only thing that bothered me when using Prolog is the fact that I don't have random access in lists (no arrays).

Answer (score 2):

Prolog is a very high level programming language. An analogy could be (Prolog : C) as (C : Assembler)

Why is not used that much then? I think that it has to do with the machines we use; They are based on turing machines. C can be compiled into byte code automatically, but Prolog is compiled to run on an emulation of the Abstract Warren Machine, thus, it is not that efficient.

Also, prolog is based on first order logic which is not capable of solving every solvable problem in a declarative manner, thus, at some point, you need to rely on imperative-like code.

Comment: Can you give an instance of a problem that's not solvable in Prolog?

Comment: @alexraasch Prolog is turing complete, so it is capable of solving the solvable. However, if you try to solve, for example, a system of equations with prolog your code would be imperative-like.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say prolog works well for problems where a knowledge base forms an important part of the solution.  Especially when the knowledge structure is suited to be encoded as logical rules.

For example, writing a natural language interpreter for a particular problem domain would require a lot of knowledge in that domain. Expert systems also fall within this knowledge driven category.

It's also a nice language to explore solutions to logical puzzles ;-)

Comment: yeah, I just solved the eight queens problem with it, and it was so easy... i don't know why we don't use Prolog more often.

Comment: @eSKay - two big ones, A). wrong tool for the job syndrome, because the majority of business problems turn out to be more about manipulating objects and OO is consequently a very prevalent and successful paradigm B). prolog is incredibly difficult to grok, and an unholy nightmare to debug

Answer (score 1):

I have been programming (for fun) over a year with Swi-Prolog. I think one of the advantages of Prolog is that Prolog has no side effects: Prolog is language that kind of has no use for (local or class member) variables, it kind of forces the programmer not use variables. Prolog objects have no state, kind of. I think. I have been writing command line Prolog (no GUI, except few XPCE tests): it is like a train on a track.